# Proguard: obfuscate classes with main() that have specific annotation

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

We all do:

```
  -keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  }
```

But I'd like to be able to annotate the main that may be obfuscated:

```
@ObfuscateMe
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

How can I tell Proguard to keep all the classes with a main, but obfuscate those with a main that have this annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible:
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/discussion/182455/thread/4b713549/

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~